# Is there a limit to the use of the Inclusion-exclusion principle for probability?

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

I'm scratching my head over this probability problem - can you help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

The problem states:
$P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 0.25;$
$P(\color{red}{B}C) = 0;$ 
$P(AB) = P(AC) = 0.15.$

The question asks: What is the probability that at least one of A, B, or C occurs?

---

The provided solution is $0.45,$ using the formula:

$P(A ~\text{or} ~B ~\text{or} ~ C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(AB) - P(AC) - P(AC) + P(A ~\color{red}{\text{and}} ~B ~\color{red}{\text{and}} ~C).$

But here's what's confusing me -

if $~P(AC)=0 ~\text{and} ~P(AB)=P(AC)=0.15,~$ 
shouldn't $~P(AB) + P(AC)~$ already be $~0.3~$?

That is, the probability value of $~P(AC)~$ cannot be 0.

Comment: You specify $P(AC)=0$ and $P(AC)=.15$ which is a contradiction

Comment: The last part of your formula should be $+P(A\text{ and }B\text{ and }C)$

Comment: You have several typos.  Hopefully, after the typos are corrected the answer will become clear.  As for $P(ABC)$ here... recall that $P(ABC)\leq \min(P(AB),P(AC),P(BC))$ so if one of those was zero...whichever of those it happened to be... implies $P(ABC)$ is zero as well.

Comment: As to the question in the title... inclusion-exclusion does what inclusion-exclusion does.  If it is helpful to your situation, then it will be helpful.  If it is not helpful, then it isn't.  I can't really elaborate further... but questions where it is heavily implied that inclusion-exclusion will be helpful like this one, it certainly will be.

Comment: As to what the typo probably is.. it is probably intended to be $P(BC)=0$ while $P(AB)=P(AC)=0.15$.  You'd get $P(A\cup B\cup C) = 0.25+0.25+0.25-0.15-0.15-0+0 = 0.45$

Comment: Going forward, with your future postings on MathSE, please proofread your posting, either before you post, or after you post or both.  While proofreading, please look for and correct typos.  Also, please (in general) make your posting easier to read, by judicious use of   line breaks, which are done via `<br>`, and paragraph breaks.  As a general quide to MathSE protocol, you can consult [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).